# Exponential martingale and random walks

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, random-walk

> Consider the assymtric random walk $(S_n)_n$ on $\mathbb{Z}$. Determine $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$ such that $\exp(\lambda S_n-a_n)_{n \ge 0}$ is a martingale. (We assume that $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X_n)] < \infty$.

I tried to check the martingale property, i.e.

$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_{n+1}-a_{n+1}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_{n}-a_{n})].$$

So far I got the following:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_{n+1}-a_{n+1}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}] &= \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_{n}+\lambda X_{n+1}-a_{n+1}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_{n}) \exp(\lambda X_{n+1}-a_{n+1}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_{n}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}] \cdot \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X_{n+1}-a_{n+1}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_{n})] \cdot \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X_{n+1}-a_{n+1}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}]
\end{align*}

However, I am not so sure what to do with $\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X_{n+1}-a_{n+1}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}]$. Does it suffice to write

$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X_{n+1}-a_{n+1}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X_{n+1}-a_{n+1})] $$

and thus

$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_{n+1}-a_{n+1}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{n+1}] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_{n})] \cdot \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X_{n}-a_{n+1})] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_{n+1}-a_{n+1})] \qquad ?$$

But what should this have to do with the $(a_n)_n$?

Comment: The martingale property should be $$ \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_{n + 1} - a_{n + 1}) \vert \mathcal{F}_n] = \exp(\lambda S_n - a_n) $$ not  $$ \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_{n + 1} - a_{n + 1}) \vert \mathcal{F}_{n + 1}] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda S_n - a_n)] $$